# преобразования строки с список

Tags: python, строки, list

хочу преобразовать строку "0.30000000000000004" в список состоящий из каждого символа данной строки. Как это сделать?

Comment: list (строка)..

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "0.30000000000000004"
c = list(a)
```

['0', '.', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '4']

Answer (score 0):

Аналогично list(s):

```py
s = "0.30000000000000004"
lst = [с for с in s]
print(lst)
```

['0', '.', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '4']